# GViz Line charts with multiple axes

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I am working on a GViz line chart with multiple axes. My issue is that I want my second axis to start from 0 and end on 100. Whereas it starts from the actual data values it has i.e 22 - 29.

So far I have this:

[image]

Doing something like:

```
vAxis: {
        viewWindowMode:'explicit',
        viewWindow:{
          max:22,
          min:1
        }
       }
```

works perfect for the line chart where there is only 1 axis but I want this to happen only for the second axis, the first axis is exactly as intended..

For multiple axis I did:

```
private Options createDafaultOptions() {
    Options options = Options.create();
    options.setWidth(800);
    options.setHeight(HpaSupportConstants.CHART_DEFAULT_HEIGHT_PX);
    options.setPointSize(HpaSupportConstants.CHART_DEFAULT_POINT_SIZE);
    return options;
  }

  private Options createSingleAxisLineChartOptions() {
    Options options = createDafaultOptions();
    AxisOptions axisOptions = AxisOptions.create();
    TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle.create();
    axisOptions.setTextStyle(textStyle);
    options.setColors(BLUE, ORANGE);
    options.setVAxisOptions(axisOptions);
    return options;
  }

  private Options createDoubleAxisLineChartOptions() {
    Options options = createDafaultOptions();
    ViewWindow viewWindow = ViewWindow.create(); //1
    viewWindow.setMin(0);                        //2
    viewWindow.setMax(100);                      //3
    AxisOptions rightAxis = AxisOptions.create();
    rightAxis.setViewWindowMode(ViewWindowMode.EXPLICIT); //4
    rightAxis.setViewWindow(viewWindow);                  //5 
    AxisOptions leftAxis = AxisOptions.create();
    options.setColors(BLUE, RED, ORANGE);
    setAxes(options, leftAxis, rightAxis);
    return options;
  }

  private native void setAxes(
    Options options, AxisOptions leftAxis, AxisOptions rightAxis)/*-{
    options.vAxes = [leftAxis, rightAxis];
    // Set the first series to default options, the second to use the right axis.
    options.series = [{}, {targetAxisIndex: 1}];
    options.vAxes = [{textStyle:{color: '#3366cc'}}, {textStyle:{color: '#dc3912'}}];
  }-*/;
```

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to make the second axis start from 0 and to end on 100]

Other helpful Links:

[Line Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)
 [Google code Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#line_chart)

I am using GWT 2.5 in addition to GViz.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `vAxes` option to control multiple y-axes:

```
vAxes: {
    0: {
        // left axis options
    },
    1: {
        // right axis options
        viewWindow: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        }
    }
}
```

**[Edit: I see you were already doing that]**

Here's your problem.  You set the axes options correctly in the first line of the `setAxes` method:

```
options.vAxes = [leftAxis, rightAxis];
```

but then overwrite them on the last line of the `setAxes` method:

```
options.vAxes = [{textStyle:{color: '#3366cc'}}, {textStyle:{color: '#dc3912'}}];
```